# pcsx2 installation

Tags: 15.04, multiarch, pcsx2

Im a noob in over my head, can someone with experience help me (in a sort of step-by-step way would be nice) install pcsx2 in 64 bit ubuntu 15? I read something about chroot, but also multiarch, being needed? I don't really know what either of those are or how to use them. is it possible to run it off a thumb drive as well?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is by installing the pcsx2 packages through the synaptic package manager. I know this question is old but hopefully this will help someone.